# VirtualHosts + DNS Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I'm a complete linux and server noob but I've started a project in an attempt to learn. What I'm trying to do right now is get wildcard subdomains to work.

In my vhost (sites-available) file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com
```

etc..

In my domain registrar DNS settings I have an A record for @, www and * pointing to my server IP. Now to my knowledge this should be working, however when I go in my browser and browse to *.domain.com it comes up with the default apache text "It works!", when I go to straight to domain.com I can see my web page (which I want to be displaying for *.domain.com too).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious but I'm a noob :)

Comment: Damn, it was because I forgot to restart apache after changing the settings, I told you I was a noob :)

My first config works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, I forgot to restart apache.

Answer (score 3):

i never know about writing ServerAlias option like this

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com
```

if you did well for dns config, try to create vhost config for the real domain (default domain), then create another vhost config for the wildcard after all real domain vhost config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
ServerName www.abc.com
ServerAlias www.abc.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abc"
ServerAlias *.abc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: as long as you put NameVirtualHost *:80 first i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 # enable name virtualhosting
<VirtualHost *:80>  # :80, not .80
   ServerName domain.com
   ServerAlias *.domain.com # www.domain.com matches *.domain.com
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Apache comments are started with '#' characters not "//". So don't put the "//"s in your config. Replace them with '#'s.

Comment: Good point, I'll update my answer